# Why does FCM return a 400 error code when I send the JSON message below via a custom Java client

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending to multiple topics.

```
  {
    "condition": "'used_cars' in topics || 'entertainment' in topics || 'shopping' in topics || 'real_estate' in topics || 'jobs' in topics || 'news' in topics ",
    "notification": {
        "body": "Details test",
        "title": "Title test",
        "icon": "ic_stat_name",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "data": {
        "title": "Title test",
        "body": "Details test"
    }
 }
```

If send to a 3 topics it works fine and I can receive my notifications on a device. The JSON is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think the maximum number of terms in the condition is 5, and you have 6. Can you remove one and see if it works?

Btw: the maximum number of terms used to be 3, so if I'm wrong about it being increased you indeed can have no more than 3.

Comment: If the maximum is no longer 3, [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) needs an update: _Maximum two operators per topic message supported_ (in description of `condition` parameter).

Comment: I can send ok and receive notifications when I have 3 topics or less. Anything above that and I get the 400 response code. You are right it appears there is a 3 topic limit. Docs do need updating. Thank you.